# CSS not loading completely when i run my python application

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I intend to apply basic CSS over my HTML under my python/ flask application. I got a HTML with CSS file from getbootstrap.com.

Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/cover/

The HTML loads up completely when I run it locally (outside the project) but it does not load properly when I try running the application using flask on dev (localhost).

Can someone please suggest a fix here. I have tried placing the CSS file in static folder and then loading it with below approach (adding link to CSS file in my HTML):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/cover.css') }}">
```

My project directory looks like:

- env
- static > stylesheets > cover.css
- templates > index.html
- app.py

app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def base():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

By default it comes with the following link:

```
 <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After running the project, it looks like as attached under the snap. This means that the CSS is getting applied but not completely.
[image]

Comment: Did you include the `bootstrap.css` file? In the demo you link to, it's `/docs/5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Hi, the following link was included already

`<link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

after your comment, i went to see further updates and the below version/ link was available:

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">`

after including this link it worked.

Thank you